# linux keyboard input logging - keymap translation

Tags: linux, keyboard, c++

I am writing a class that monitors input events on linux. 
It'll be used in a daemon that acts upon a user's keypresses in gui programs to give visual feedback on a usb led device.

I use input events I read from /dev/input/event*. I am using `<linux/input.h>` and I get the keycodes.

I am on a belgian keyboard. I press and release the 'A' key on my keyboard and my log currently shows:

```
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.751 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.751445, type 4 (Misc), code 4 (ScanCode), value 0x10
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.751 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.751445, type 1 (Key), code 16 (Q), value 1
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.751 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.751445, -------------- Report Sync ------------
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.792 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.792115, type 4 (Misc), code 4 (ScanCode), value 0x10
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.792 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.792115, type 1 (Key), code 16 (Q), value 0
29/09/2019 - 14:14:48.792 [Info] Event: time 1569759288.792115, -------------- Report Sync ------------
```

what actually gets printed on the screen without any modifier keys is a small 'a'

notice the 'code 16 (Q)' - The number 16 is the base 10 keycode.

I now need to map that 'Q' to my keyboard layout and in this case it should log 'a'.
To that extend I use the dumpkeys program to get my kernel's current translation tables.

As far as this specific example is concerned the shortened data (only 4 columns shown) it outputs is:

```
keycode  16 = +a               +A               at               VoidSymbol
```

or in a more suitable format:

```
keycode  16 = +0x0b61          +0x0b41          0x0040           0x0200
```

The + means shiftable by default. At this stage I am not sure if that is something I need to take into account so I strip that.

As I understand it the dumpkeys program adds 0xb00 to the correct number so, I drop the +, substract 0x0b00 from 0x0b61 to obtain 0x0061.

0x0061 is the unicode number U+0061 for 'a' and I store that QString in a vector on location 0, so, the first column as far as dumpkeys is concerned.

Now for the problems:

Some keys are ok. If I interpret the data for the physical key that has the characters '1' '&' '|' on my keyboard it all checks out with the modifier keys.

But for this example ( the physical key only carries a capital 'A' ) it's not ok.

According to the modifier rules explained in the keymaps(5) - Linux man page the following should occur:

I press keycode 16 without any modifier key and I get U+0061 or 'a' -> ok - action number zero (from the 1st column)

I press keycode 16 with shift modifier key and I get U+0041 or 'A' -> ok as the shift modifier has weight 1, so action number one (from the 2nd column)

I press keycode 16 with AltGr modifier key and I get U+0040 or '@' -> ok, AltGr weight 2 - so action number two (from the 3th column)

Now, if I press keycode 16 together with Shift and AltGr the weight adds up to 3, so action number three (from the 4th column) aka VoidSymbol so nothing shoud occur. What I get though is a capital omega 'Ω'. Why?

As for that VoidSymbol, U+0200 is actually Ȁ (Latin Capital Letter a with Double Grave). How does one print that character then if it's unicode value is used as VoidSymbol?

There are other issues too.

Another example is the physical key that has '§','6','^' on it. The keymap dumpkeys gives me has no trace of the '§' character (U+00A7). Yet, I am able to type it...

What's up with the shiftable by default?

EDIT: additional question

```
#define modifierShift 1;    //why the difference between ShiftL and ShiftR -> there is no 'shift' key
#define modifierControl 4;  //why the difference between ControlL and ControlR -> there is no 'control' key
#define modifierShiftL 16;  //code 42
#define modifierShiftR 32;  //code 54
#define modifierCtrlL 64;   //code 29
#define modifierCtrlR 128;  //code 97
```

Can someone clarify this for me please?

Comment: Are you using X (a graphical environment)? If yes, does `xev` give you the correct keys? If yes, is it a hard requirement that you use the kernel input layer, or could you also intercept keys on the X layer?

Comment: Yes, using X. xev gives the correct keys. I know of some users that aren't using X though it is rare. I'll have a look at intercepting keyboard strikes at the x server level but I would rather stick with the kernel input layer - if possible of course. If you know why I have the kernel layer issues please do share. Some small x-server keyboard event c++ code is welcome too.

Comment: So far it looks like you Belgian keyboard is only selected on the X layer, which is why you don't see the correct keys on the kernel input layer. Trying `loadkeys` with a Belgian keymap in `/usr/share/keymaps/i386/azerty`, first on the console, then see if it also works with X.

Comment: I installed console-data. I loaded be-latin1.kmap.gz and if I run dumpkeys I now have the correct keycode   7 = paragraph        six              dead_circumflex  VoidSymbol       Control_asciicircum VoidSymbol for one of the keys I described above so it looks ok now. What that means for the class itself... I need to let it sink in a bit. How can one detect keys reliably? I don't see it atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux uses two sets of keymappings. One works on the kernel input layer level, and assigns a keycode to a scancode. You can use `loadkeys` to change this mapping. This is what you see in `evtest`.

Another one works on the X server level. X has (among others) a generic `evdev` driver that collects input events from the kernel input layer, and then maps those to so-called keysyms. This is what you see in `xev`. You can modify this with `xmodmap` and through the xkbd extensions in a more general way.

So if you have users that are not using X, you have two choices: Act on the scancode of the key (i.e., the position of the key on the keyboard, so you implement your own keymapping), or act on the key as translated in the kernel, and instruct your users to use `loadkeys` etc. to load their keymapping of choice.

Both methods are "reliable", but have very different semantics.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. I'll be able to sort it out with the info you gave me.

Comment: I'm yet having another look and for keycode 16 I described above I still don't have the Ω in column 4 in the keymap. Do you know how that functions?